# How to combine two tables (with same schema) into a single table with distinct values and indicating which table each row came from?

Tags: sql

Suppose that I have two tables in SQL:

```
Table_Alpha   Table_Bravo
Id | Name     Id | Name
---+------    ---+-----
 1 | Alice     1 | Charlie
 2 | Bob       2 | Bob
 3 | Charlie   3 | Dorothy
```

I want to combine the two tables into a single table, avoiding duplicates and keeping track of which table each name came from like so:

```
Result
Name   | Alpha | Bravo
-------+-------+------
Alice  |   1   |   0  
Bob    |   1   |   1  
Charlie|   1   |   1  
Dorothy|   0   |   1
```

I think that the query that I want will look something like this:

```
SELECT Name, 1 AS Alpha, 0 AS Bravo FROM Table_Alpha
UNION
SELECT Name, 0 AS Alpha, 1 AS Bravo FROM Table_Bravo;
```

However, the above query will return two rows for each name that appears in both tables.  How can I write the query so that it will return one row for each distinct name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, sum(Alpha) as 'Alpha', sum(Bravo) as 'Bravo'
FROM (
    SELECT Name, 1 as Alpha, 0 as Bravo from Table_Alpha
    UNION
    SELECT Name, 0 as Alpha, 1 as Bravo from Table_Bravo
) X
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: That fits the OP's request if you add `Group By Name`.

Comment: Very close! The SQL server I'm working with required me to add a `GROUP BY` clause, and so I dropped the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FULL JOIN` and if the `Name` columns do not have duplicates, no `GROUP BY` is needed:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name),
    CASE WHEN a.Name IS NOT NULL THE 1 ELSE 0 END AS Alpha,
    CASE WHEN b.Name IS NOT NULL THE 1 ELSE 0 END AS Bravo
FROM
    Table_Alpha AS a
  FULL JOIN
    Table_Bravo AS b
      ON a.Name = b.Name ;
```

If there are duplicates:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name),
    COUNT(a.Name) AS Alpha,
    COUNT(b.Name) AS Bravo
FROM
    Table_Alpha AS a
  FULL JOIN
    Table_Bravo AS b
      ON a.Name = b.Name 
GROUP BY 
    COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) ;
```